# Understanding pointers, dereference etc

Tags: c++

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

int justInt = 10;
int* pointerToInt = &justInt; 
int** pointerToPointer = &pointerToInt; //Why are 2 asteriks necessary? I thought at first that's because it would actually just point to 'justInt', but I checked and it points to 'pointerToInt' as expected.



void* voidPointerToInt = &justInt; //Can't be dereferenced unless we specify type because it's void.

cout << *pointerToInt << "\n";


cout << *(int*)voidPointerToInt;// How do you put into English "*(int*)"? Not sure what it effectively does step-by-step except that it takes 4 bytes from the start of address and puts them into an int, however that works.

/*          //I took a look into the disassembly, don't really know it very well though.

mov         eax,dword ptr [voidPointerToInt] ;Eax stores the memlocation of voidPointerToInt as I watched the registers change. But I thought that the [] would dereference it? EDIT: I forgot that all variables in masm are pointers until you dereference them. So, if the [] weren't there then we would move a pointer to 'voidPointerToInt' into eax instead of its value.
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]              ;Ecx becomes 10, as it dereferences the 4 bytes stored at the begining of memlocation that eax stores.

;Not sure what the rest is for.
push        ecx                              
mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0EF10A4h]      
call        dword ptr ds:[0EF1090h]  
cmp         esi,esp  
call        __RTC_CheckEsp (0EE1343h)  
*/

cin.ignore();
```

}

pointerToInt stores the memory location of justInt. The 'int' indicates that the pointer points to an integer, so we can dereference it.

Why is "int pointerToInt = &justInt;" invalid? What if I want to store the mem location in a normal int. It's 4 bytes on 32bit, so what's the issue? Same goes with dereferencing a normal int.

Would there be a difference between an int* and a normal int that stores a memory address?

Comment: What do you mean `int* pointerToInt = &justInt;` _is invalid_? It actually isn't?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The line in the text is different from the line in the code snippet - an asterix is missing in the text...

Comment: @cmaster Well, and an obelisk might be missing too ;) ...

Comment: "How do you put into English `*(int*)`? "   - I'd say "star int star"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its actually a whole bunch of questions, that make little sense to be answered in the StackOverflow format.

Comment: There are a lot of individual questions in there. It may be better to actually ask each of them separately. And I sense a programmer's mind too obsessed with irrelevant low-level implementation details.

Comment: The extra assembly on the end looks like some sort of stack overflow checking that your compiler is inserting (it might go away if you compile in release mode / optimizations on)

Comment: Alright. And I also just figured out why it does 'eax, [voidPointerToInt]' I forgot that all variables in masm are just memory locations and need to be dereferenced. I'll edit OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that `pointerToPointer` points to has type `int *`.  The type which points to `X` is `X*`, so the type which points to `int *` is `int **`.

---

`cout << *(int*)voidPointerToInt;` has the same effect as `cout << *pointerToInt`.   The `void *` is a generic pointer type ; you can think of it has a non-tagged variant if that would help  .  It can be used for transporting pointers of different types over a common interface.

In your code you convert `pointerToInt` to `void *` and then back to its original type `int *`, restoring the original value.

Using code: it could be said that if `X` has type `int *`, then `(int *)((void *)X) == X` .